# Create series instance as a concrete object

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is there a way to instantiate a series object as a concrete object when building the series for initial rendering of graph:

Ex:

```
var graphSeries = {}; //Is there a way to construct a real series object
graphSeries.name = country.name;
graphSeries.color = country.color;
graphSeries.data = [];
graphSeries.data.push(country.year2010);

graphData.series.push(graphSeries);
chart = new Highcharts.Chart(graphData);
```

This is for the initial rendering of the chart.

I would like to avoid constructing `graphSeries` as an anonymous object in order to get access to the methods on the real series object. Is there a helper method available to create the object?

Something like:

```
var graphSeries = HichChartObject.CreateSeries();
```

I know there is a way to reference the series objects after the chart has been rendered like this:

```
chart.series[index].remove();
```

But I would like to keep a reference to the added series and instead do

```
graphSeries.remove();
```

Comment: just make it into a constructor function and attach it to HichChartObject.prototype

Comment: I don't want to construct it myself because I want the methods on the series prototype

Comment: Why would you want or need to do this? Probably what happens is internally high charts will merge the parameters you provide with a bunch of default values to create the real `series` object. This is pretty common practice in JavaScript.

Comment: It's mainly because I want to associate the series instance with my view model, so that I can just interact with it directly instead of keeping an indirect index based reference to it. It's also desirable to not have to reference the chart instance in the view model

Comment: This would also allow for asynch removal since I don't have to worry about maintaining the index

Comment: @TGH: I highly doubt that would work. I doubt that the series itself keeps a reference to the parent chart, so you'd still need to maintain a reference to it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In series we also use {} elements, but you can try to use javascript new Object();